# How can I make a check on a string to narrow it down to the strings in an enum, and have TypeScript recognize it (node example)?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Using basic node.js, in `http.createServer` I am taking the `request`, and taking the `path` from the request. I have a `router` object, keyed by paths, with values being handler functions.

```
// index.ts

export interface DataObject {
  queryStringObject: ParsedUrlQuery;
  method: string;
  headers: IncomingHttpHeaders;
  payload: any;
}

export type HandlerCallback = (statusCode: number, payload?: Object) => any;

export type Handler = (data: DataObject, callback: HandlerCallback) => any;

interface Router {
  ping: Handler;
  users: Handler;
  adminUsers: Handler;
  tokens: Handler;
}

// Define request router
const router: Router = {
  ping: handlers.ping,
  users: handlers.users,
  adminUsers: handlers.adminUsers,
  tokens: handlers.tokens,
};

export enum RestMethods {
  get = 'get',
  post = 'post',
  put = 'put',
  delete = 'delete',
}

export type RestHandler = {
  [method in RestMethods]: Handler;
};
```

Then, I have the file where `handlers` is defined:

```
interface Handlers {
  users: Handler;
  adminUsers: Handler;
  tokens: Handler;
  notFound: Handler;
  ping: Handler;
}

interface SubHandlers {
  users: RestHandler;
  adminUsers: RestHandler;
  tokens: RestHandler;
}

export const handlers: Handlers = {
  users: (data, callback) => {
    const acceptableMethods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'];
    if (acceptableMethods.indexOf(data.method) !== -1) {
      subHandlers.users[data.method](data, callback);
    }
  },
(...)
```

I get a `typescript` error on the line `subhandlers.users[data.method]...`

> Error:(62, 14) TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Router'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Router'.

`data.method` is a `string` because `DataObject` defines it that way (an incoming request could have anything in `method`), and `subhandlers.users` is of type `RestHandler`, which is an object with keys in the enum `RestMethods`. But I am doing the check `acceptableMethods.indexOf(data.method) !== -1`... How can I make this check so that Typescript can realize that data.method has been restricted to only the strings that are in the enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here; one is that `acceptableMethods` is inferred to be of type `string[]`, whereas you want the compiler to keep track of the string literal values it contains; you can fix that easily enough with a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) as in:

```
const acceptableMethods = ["get", "post", "put", "delete"] as const;
```

The second issue is that TypeScript does not understand or expect that, given an array `array` of type `T[]` and a value `val`, checking `array.indexOf(val) !== -1` should narrow `val` to type `T`.  Luckily you can get this behavior by making a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function arrayIncludes<T>(
  arr: ReadonlyArray<T>,
  val: any
): val is T {
  return arr.indexOf(val) !== -1;
}
```

Now you can use `arrayIncludes()` in place of the `indexOf` check, and it should work for you:

```
export const handlers: Handlers = {
  users: (data, callback) => {
    const acceptableMethods = ["get", "post", "put", "delete"] as const;
    if (arrayIncludes(acceptableMethods, data.method)) {
      subHandlers.users[data.method](data, callback); // okay
    }
  }
};
```

Does that help?  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFsHsBMEsDNYFNqgMYyaARkgNpAO6gAukEAhgNZYUSwB2s4AruKAE5IAOHMLaWNjxYkADwrhuIgFAzx3SBxKhGJJB3gU0WACIUSFAPLYAVkjQqA3jNAQkJABYwAXKADOJDowDmAbhkAXzkFJRUSAE9uLAAJCgZoEQ4AYQo8PGxtKlAAXlAACk8DFndkzDcGNlwOABpQbgoIggpoAH43E3NLAEpcgD5QeIiA+TFFZVIo2PjEjVyC6AMKN31DTosSOrQ0jKy3OISk1PTMtCpenIGhkbUNLR1QACVIFnUOUBs7Eo13fZmkgLBUbjFRISrsR5ITwAWQczmg7g+tlAPgc8wARKiSOiasjFJ4Mfjsbi7NxXoTXjjkdB8A4sHl0TSROp0UEQmMwpNok8oSQDrN3nkrKAANrgOEwVQMHkwiUIgC6f0Oc0CNwYb3u02VHERn1A3x1SoFgLkt002iwAGUWNh+UldciDb8ZXz-hoTTS0HgKFx0JAGAT3Da7T83NbbW6dSMQDHY3H4wnE0nkynU3J4CwGJZYP7BhwOI0AJJZvAsGnuAA8ABU+vkfRw3JCWv68BEAIL5xrVvp1ABuaTcQ26bn7eFUiKrSLsXBILA40vrADpGDSxEZ4PlR70AIQ5PIAWgAjCbgZyMAGVI5I86Qzr5nqnW58otDFsdqdzv0p3Y-RfBmgdG4QxhCQWEnBgRE8hFTEHBxUB0SJOCEMpOpGVpFl5UGRFz08AIf1UeACnrIsSzLKE6wAnhgJEMD4XcOoXwoRdxXA6Bul6PV8KDCNtXcRcnRFRjmLleVnyWN8Tiybo8J-YI7GCVUZCAA)

Comment: One thing I did that solved the issue as well was `data.method as RestMethods`.